# Floated buttons won't go beneath an inline edit popup

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a table, and in the `tbody` I have an inline edit popup that is absolute positioned.

I have a table footer that has display `inline-block` that contains buttons that are floated to the left and right. It looks like:

```
<div class="table-footer">
        <div class="new-row-button">
            <lightning-button variant="base" label="New Row" title="Add new row" icon-name="utility:add" onclick={addNewRow}></lightning-button>
        </div>

        <template if:true={changesWereMade}>
            <div class="save-cancel-wrapper">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Ok" title="Make changes" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Discard changes" onclick={revertChanges} class="slds-m-left_xx-small"></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
```

What happens is I end up with this:

[image]

Even though the drop down supposedly has a z-index of 9001. The inline editor is inside the tbody tag. I have tried to raise the z-index of the tbody element, the table element, the inline editor, no luck in getting it to go over those buttons. The only thing I got to work was make the table-footer relative positioned and assign a z-index of -1. But this makes my buttons unclickable as they are now 'below' the page.

Does anyone have any css advice on how to get these buttons underneath the inline editor? (The table element and table-footer div are at the same level in the element hierarchy)

Comment: increase the z-index of the dropdown wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display flex css property for your footer to replace the float. Something like this :

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .button {
  flex: 1;
}

footer .button:first-of-type {
  align-self:start;
}

footer .button:last-of-type {
  align-self:end;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <button> Add me </button>
  <button> Delete me </button>
</footer>
```

Hope to help you.